# How to verify Admob Rewarded Video Ad on a server?

Tags: firebase, admob, admob-rewardedvideoad

Is there a way to verify if the Rewarded Video Ad was watched by client (OnAdRewarded) on a server? Is there any integration I can use with Google Cloud Functions?

I thought it's possible to verify a token sent by client to the server with admob admin SDK but it seems that it's not possible and we can only verify the ad on the client.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is now possible with [Server-Side Verification (SSV) Callbacks.](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/rewarded-video-ssv#perform_verification)

> Server-side verification callbacks are URL requests, with query parameters expanded by Google, that are sent by Google to an external system to notify it that a user should be rewarded for interacting with a rewarded video ad. Rewarded video SSV (server-side verification) callbacks provide an extra layer of protection against spoofing of client-side callbacks to reward users.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure this is relevant to Firebase but here are some details in case anyone is using Node / JS. You can use Node's inbuilt `crypto` library. First `fetch` the available Google AdMob verifier keys from `https://gstatic.com/admob/reward/verifier-keys.json`.

You'll then need to loop through the returned JSON `keys` array and grab the `pem` public key file string corresponding to the `req.query.key_id` parameter of your incoming `req.url` string.

Then the "message" we wish to verify signatures with is the incoming `req.url` substring inbetween the parameter `?` symbol and  `&signature...` strings.

Now we can verify easily:

```
   const verifier = crypto.createVerify("sha256");
   
   verifier.update(message);
   
   if(verifier.verify(pem, req.query.signature, "base64"))
      console.log("Ad was successfully verified.");
   else
      console.log("Ad could not be verified - quick call the cops !");
```

One caveat to beware of is you may need to `unescape(...)` your `req.url` string before you use it since some characters may have been escaped. I was stuck on that for a good hour or two. You can do this using e.g. Node's built in `querystring` library.

Comment: I am Node JS newbie, can you share code or example? thanks

Comment: All the info is in the answer, with example for verifying. Compare and contrast it with Google's Java equivalent: https://developers.google.com/admob/android/ssv you'll learn a lot that way. Note that using Google's Tink JS library would be much easier, (it's explained in that link) although it's in Alpha at the mo so that's why I rolled my own. But that's also explained in that link too ! For starters you could enter the gstatic HTTPS link into a browser for example.

Comment: Also note my references to `req.*` (request) above relate to the Express library form of creating your Node / JS endpoints. Explore https://expressjs.com/ to learn how to setup a Node / JS / Express server. Although you don't need to use Express. Check out Mosh's really good tutorials on Node / JS / etc: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pKd0Rpw7O48

Comment: unescape(...) your req.url  => save me time. Some query string not match with original from google admob if we don't unescape()

Answer (score 1):

Not at the moment. The feature has been in closed beta for a while from what I've gathered recently. The last mention I could find was in the linked discussion where someone, from Google presumably, says the feature will be rolled out to the public soon. The post is from Jan 22.

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-admob-ads-sdk/weXTAGZfYQ8

Answer (score 1):

I know its a bit late but here is a piece of code that helped me. It is in javascript for Node users.
https://github.com/hypeben/admob-rewarded-ads-ssv

```
const queryString = require('query-string');
const crypto = require('crypto');
const axios = require('axios');
const GOOGLE_AD_KEY_URL = 'https://gstatic.com/admob/reward/verifier-keys.json';

/**
 * Fetches the google public keys for the admob providers.
 * These keys changes time to time.
 */
 const getGoogleKeysMap = async () => {
 let googleKeyRes = await axios.get(GOOGLE_AD_KEY_URL);
 let {keys} = googleKeyRes.data;
 if (!keys) {
 throw new Error('No keys found from google keys');
 }
 /** For each of the keys array save it base 64 in decoded form in the key map */
 let keyMap = {};
 keys.forEach(k => {
 keyMap[`${k.keyId}`] = crypto.createPublicKey(k.pem);
 console.log(keyMap[`${k.keyId}`]);
 });
 return keyMap;
 };

/**
 * Verifies the callback url query params string,
 * Resolves the promise if verification was successful, else fails.
 * Wanna 'debug' then pass the second parameter as true.
  * @param {String} queryUrl
  * @param {Boolean} debug 
 */
async function verify(queryUrl, debug) {

try {

if (typeof queryUrl !== "string") throw new TypeError("URL needs to be string!");

/**
 * Request coming as callback from admob must contain the 'signature' and the  'user_id'.
 * For more info https://developers.google.com/admob/android/rewarded-video-ssv
 */
const {signature, key_id} = queryString.parse(queryUrl);
if (!signature) {
  throw new Error('No signature value exist in the URL param');
}

if(debug) {
  console.debug('Signature and KeyId ---');
  console.debug(signature, key_id);
//  console.log('Signature and KeyId ---');
//  console.log(signature, key_id);
}

let queryParamsString = queryUrl;
if (queryParamsString.indexOf('?') > -1) {
  queryParamsString = queryUrl.split('?')[1];
}

if(debug) {
  console.debug('Query param string ---');
 // console.log('Query param string ---');
  console.debug(queryParamsString);
 // console.log(queryParamsString);
}

/**
 * As per admob, 
 * The last two query parameters of rewarded video SSV callbacks are always signature and key_id, in that order.
 * The remaining query parameters specify the content to be verified. 
 */
let contentToVerify = queryParamsString.substring(0, queryParamsString.indexOf('signature') -1);

if(debug) {
  console.debug('Content to verify ---');
 // console.log(contentToVerify);
 // console.log('Content to verify ---');
  console.debug(contentToVerify);
}

let keyMap = await getGoogleKeysMap();

if(keyMap[`${key_id}`]) {
  let publicKey = keyMap[`${key_id}`];
  const verifier = crypto.createVerify('RSA-SHA256');
  verifier.update(contentToVerify);
  let result = verifier.verify(publicKey, signature, 'base64');
  if (result) {
    console.debug('Result ---');
     console.debug(result);
    return true;
  } else {
    console.debug('Failure ---');
    console.debug(result);
    throw new Error('Invalid Signature Supplied');
  }
} else {
  console.debug('Key id provided doesn\'t exist ---');
  throw new Error('Key id provided doesn\'t exist in the google public keys');
}


  } catch (error) {

 }

}

module.exports.verify = verify;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you guys looking for a simple way on Golang for the Admob SSV.

Just use this [hiyali/go-lib-ssv](https://github.com/hiyali/go-lib-ssv), hope to save your life :)

Answer (score 0):

I have done this to confirm the server side:

**Step1**: make Rest API for google callback: i wrote in c# :)

```
 [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class GoogleVerifyController : ControllerBase
    {

        // GET: api/Configs

        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<Response> GetGoogleVerify()
        {
            IQueryCollection query = Request.Query;  
            string? userId = query["user_id"];
            if (userId is null)
            {
                return new Response { Data = "the user token id is null.", Status = false, StatusCode = 400 };
            }

            //do somthing
 };


        }



    }
```

**Step 2:** Add user-id and custom data to the ad object in the app (only for reward and rewarded interstitial) :

```
lateinit var serverSideVerificationOptions: ServerSideVerificationOptions;

fun initServerSideVerificationOptions() {
    val s = GlobalStorage.token()
    serverSideVerificationOptions = ServerSideVerificationOptions
        .Builder()
        .setCustomData(GlobalStorage.deviceId())
        .setUserId(s)
        .build()
    if (serverSideVerificationOptions != null) {
            rewardedInterstitialAd.setServerSideVerificationOptions(serverSideVerificationOptions);
        }
   
}
```

**Step 3**: add your API URL in admob console > apps > your app > ad units > reward/rewardedInterstitial unit id > advance setting > Server-side verification and save it